# What visible star is closest to the ecliptic?

Tags: ecliptic

If we were to project the ecliptic out as an infinite plane, what visible star (besides the sun) would lie closest to it?

Answer (score 2):

[Regulus ($\alpha$ Leo)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulus) is the one to beat, with ecliptic latitude $\beta$ = +0.46$^\circ$ and apparent V magnitude +1.4.
Some dimmer stars are closer to the ecliptic, e.g.
[$\alpha$ Lib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Librae) ($\beta$=+0.33$^\circ$, V=+2.7),
[$\delta$ Gem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_Geminorum) ($\beta$=-0.18$^\circ$, V=+3.5), and
[$\delta$ Cnc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_Cancri) ($\beta$=+0.08$^\circ$, V=+3.9).
For more suggestions, poke around in Stellarium with the Ecliptic turned on.

If you want linear distance from the ecliptic plane, multiply the distance from us by $\sin \beta$.

Answer (score 2):

HIP 76880 = $\kappa$ Librae (V=4.72) has an Ecliptic latitude of -0.019 degrees.

This is the winner amongst all stars in the Hipparco/Tycho catalogue with a Hipparcos magnitude <6.

If you mean physical distance, rather than angular distance, then the sine of the ecliptic latitude must be multiplied by a distance estimate for the star. This cannot be conclusive, the distances to many naked eye stars are very uncertain, a small fraction of Hipparcos parallaxes are too uncertain to be useful in this regard.
However, from those with decent parallaxes then **HIP 3765 = HD 4628** (V=5.72) has an absolute distance of 0.036 pc above the ecliptic plane.

Comment: $\gamma^2$ Nor *ecliptic* latitude is -28.3 degrees.

Comment: @MikeG Aaaargh, I put in Galactic coords!

Comment: Now fixed (I hope).